# How to read all rows of a csv file using pandas in python?

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I am using the `pandas` module for reading the data from a `.csv` file.

I can write out the following code to extract the data belonging to an individual column as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('somefile.tsv', sep='\t', header=0)
some_column = df.column_name
print some_column # Gives the values of all entries in the column
```

However, the file that I am trying to read now has more than 5000 columns and writing out the statement

```
some_column = df.column_name
```

is now not feasible. How can I get all the column values so that I can access them using indexing?

e.g to extract the value present at the 100th row and the 50th column, I should be able to write something like this:

```
df([100][50])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) or [`DataFrame.iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iat.html), but python counts from `0`, so need `99` and `49` for select `100.` row and `50.` column:

```
df = df.iloc[99,49]
```

Sample - select `3.` row and `4.` column:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                   'B':[4,5,6],
                   'C':[7,8,9],
                   'D':[1,3,10],
                   'E':[5,3,6],
                   'F':[7,4,3]})

print (df)
   A  B  C   D  E  F
0  1  4  7   1  5  7
1  2  5  8   3  3  4
2  3  6  9  10  6  3

print (df.iloc[2,3])
10

print (df.iat[2,3])
10
```

Combination for selecting by column name and position of row is possible by [`Series.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iloc.html) or [`Series.iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iat.html):

```
print (df['D'].iloc[2])
10

print (df['D'].iat[2])
10
```

Comment: Thanks. Works as desired

Comment: Moreover, how do I find out the total number of columns from df variable?

Comment: do you think `len(df.columns)` ?

Comment: Thanks a lot @jezrael. Works as expected

Comment: Glad can help you!

Comment: You can upvote too - click to small triangle above `1` above accepting mark if dont accepting yet. Thanks.

Comment: Yesm I recently achieved this ability.

Answer (score 1):

Pandas has indexing for dataframes, so you can use

```
df.iloc[[index]]["column header"]
```

the index is in a list as you can pass multiple indexes at one in this way.